# Why is npm start is not working on my React app?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to star my project and when I run: npm start I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\albat\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\albat\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\albat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T12_44_42_310Z-debug.log
```

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: read the error message: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\albat\package.json'`. Change to the directory where the package.json is located

Answer (score -1):

Did you just try **npm i**, then **npm start**. ?